# SQL in ssrs 2015 value was either too large or too small fir an INT32

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008

I have some code in the SQL side of SSRS that filters the results  on a slaes order number.

The field type for the SALES_DOC is BIGINT. When I enter the sales order number in the filter field I get the results I am expecting, when I replace the sales order  number with a filter Key ( @SALES_ORDER ), then enter the sales order number in the pop up window I then get the error message:

> Value was either too large or too small for an Int32

I have tried to cast the field to an int32 and to a bigint but still get the error as well as cast to toher data types. I dont understand why I can Key the number in the filter it works but when I use a paramater it errors out.

I also tried to upload a jpeg for the screen but it wont load :(

Thanks

Tony

Comment: Not very clear exactly where you are experiencing your issue, but if it's on an RDL parameter then the datatype for that parameter will need to be float as there is no bigint in SSRS parameter data types, only INT or Float.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to cast in *Double*.
Or maybe your *"Sales Order"* field is a *Text* type and thats why you get the error.

Comment: Thank you both I will try that this evening 